# "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" mystery (to me)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've looked through a few dozen questions about this issue and still haven't been able to figure it out.

Here's an example of what I'm doing. Note that `new_client_name` is just a string like "Walmart".

```
function one (){
   var new_client_name = allSelectedInfo.client_name;
   pickClient(new_client_name);
}

function pickClient (new_client_name){
   var new_client = new_client_name;
   $.ajax({
            url: 'php/get_cohorts.php',
            type: 'POST',
            //dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                client: new_client
            },
            success: function(data) {
                //do something
            }
        });
}
```

Both functions execute fine and I get the data I want from the ajax call and everything appears to be working fine, except for the Illegal Invocation error, which is tied to the line that starts with `$.ajax`.

What's causing this?

Comment: What browser is throwing the error? Have you confirmed that `$.ajax` is defined (e.g. by console.logging it)?

Comment: This is in Chrome. How can I console.log `$.ajax`?

Comment: `console.log($.ajax)`

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the problem. Are you sure this code contains it and that you haven't created a reduced test case where the problem is one of the things you've removed?

Comment: `$.ajax` looks fine. I've tried about 20 different things with the same result so far.

Comment: I don't see where function `two` gets called at all.  Is that the same as `pickClient`?

Comment: @GaryStorey Good catch. That was a typo when I was putting my example together. Any thoughts now?

Comment: In my experience Illegal Invocation errors tend to be about what's being stored in the data value. Can you look at `new_client` and double check it is actually a string and not an object or something hinky.

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(new_client);` ?

Comment: @M.Doye This is weird. When I do that, I get back a simple string with the value I expect on one line in the console and in the next line (referring to the same line in my code), I get this: `m.Event {type: "shown", timeStamp: 1429724707381, jQuery111206514598985668272: true, isTrigger: 3, namespace: "bs.modal"…}`